# doesn't work wired / wireless networks

Tags: wireless, wired

I installed Ubuntu by WUBI along side Windows 8, with no problems. But I cannot connect to the internet, wireless or wired.

It's my first time using Ubuntu, so I don't know how to do a lot of things.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: i'm not sure that it's a right information. Wired : Qualcomm atheros AR8161 PCI-E Gigabite Ethernet Controller(Ndis 6.30) Wireless : intel@centrino @advanced-N 6235

Comment: Please run `sudo ifconfig` and post it's output inside your question.

Answer (score 1):

For the wireless you can try:

`echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`

`sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi`

`sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi`

Watch for errors. Also try channel 1 or 11 in your router they usually work best. Set your router to just wpa2 not mixed mode if you have that option and also set security in network manager to wpa/wpa2.

You can usually access your router by typing 192.168.0.1 into your broswer but some times it is different numbers needed in that case refer to your routers manual.